# Spring Security - The request was rejected because the URL contained a potentially malicious String "//"

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat, spring-security

I found an interesting exception in my logs:

```
org.springframework.security.web.firewall.RequestRejectedException: The request was rejected because the URL contained a potentially malicious String "//"
    at org.springframework.security.web.firewall.StrictHttpFirewall.rejectedBlocklistedUrls(StrictHttpFirewall.java:535) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar!/:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.firewall.StrictHttpFirewall.getFirewalledRequest(StrictHttpFirewall.java:505) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar!/:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:206) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar!/:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:186) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar!/:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

I have no idea right now what is that and how to properly configure my SpringBoot application in order to manage that. Please advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring security by default uses `StrictHttpFirewall` to reject any suspicious HTTP request. It will consider the URL as suspicious if it contains the character sequences `//`

For the reasons why it needs to do that and what attack it is trying to prevent , you can refer to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NQwUDLMOrHo), [this](https://i.blackhat.com/us-18/Wed-August-8/us-18-Orange-Tsai-Breaking-Parser-Logic-Take-Your-Path-Normalization-Off-And-Pop-0days-Out-2.pdf) , [this](https://tanzu.vmware.com/security/cve-2018-1199) and [this](https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-g8hw-794c-4j9g) for more information.

The first option is to play around `StrictHttpFirewall` and see if its settings allow to be configured to satisfy your need:

```java
public class Config extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
       StrictHttpFirewall firewall = new StrictHttpFirewall();
       //configure the firewall instance....
        web.httpFirewall(firewall);
    }

}
```

The second option is to use a less secured `HttpFirewall` which is called the `DefaultHttpFirewall` (though its name is `DefaultHttpFirewall` , it is not the actual default since spring security 4.2.4 :P). Use at your own risk.

```java
public class Config extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.httpFirewall(new DefaultHttpFirewall());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is gone. The modern way to do this is:

```
@Bean
public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
    StrictHttpFirewall firewall = new StrictHttpFirewall();
    firewall.setAllowBackSlash(true);
    return (web) -> web.httpFirewall(firewall);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case problem was with the return view naming in a controller.
This return generates the exception org.springframework.security.web.firewall.RequestRejectedException: The request was rejected because the URL contained a potentially malicious String "//":

```
return "/document/table/tableCardDisqualification";
```

This code works correctly:

```
return "document/table/tableCardDisqualification";
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This answer is valid if your spring-boot app is backed by Apache2 reverse configuration

I was running the same spring-boot app on multiple EC2 instances. But for one of the instances, only I faced the same error.

Found out the problem was in the Apache2 reverse proxy configuration. There was an extra "/" appended from there. Changing the apache2 configuration makes everything work out fine.